# data-ng-bind-html works but not curly {{}} brackets

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so when I use this code, the data-ng-bind-html properly displays the topics but when I actually use topic.pagetitle, nothing shows, there is an empty  tag. Anyone know what could be going on?

```
<div class="well">
<ul class="filterByTopic">
    <li ng-repeat="topic in topics">
        <a href="" data-ng-bind-html="topic.pagetitle" ng-class="{active: topic.id == activeTopic}">{{topic.pagetitle}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't make sense to use both for same element anyway.

Comment: yeah I get that, the only reason I have data-ng-bind-html there is for testing, ideally it isnt needed and just the curly braces, seems like the curly braces arent parsing

Comment: What exactly is "topic.pagetitle"?  If it contains HTML, angular will not bind it with curly brackets for security reasons.

Comment: Good tip Jason, its just a JSON data

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context. See [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Answer (score 2):

The `ngBindHtml` works by setting the innerHTML on the element. This means that anything you put inside that tag will be overwritten by the ngBindHtml value. This is mentioned at the top of the documentation for that directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Here is an example (code missing for brevity):

**CONTROLLER**

```
...
scope.foo = '<b> I am the foo </b>'
scope.bar = 'Bar'
...
```

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-bind-html="foo">{{ bar }}</div>
<div ng-bind-html="foo"></div>
<div>{{ bar }}</div>
```

**BROWSER**

**I am the foo**
**I am the foo**
Bar

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but for some reason topic.pagetitle works when I use it with ng-bind but not when I use it in curly braces {{topic.pagetitle}}, it just comes up blank, any idea why?

Comment: Not sure why that would happen. Angular automatically trusts values that are interpolated that way, so the view should print out <b>your page title</b>. Let me know if you find the issue!

Comment: This was news to me. More upvotes, for question and answer please.